# Parameter entityLocation is not specified (null/empty)

Tags: anylogic

I was trying to initializite the model but this error appears. I cant find any info about entityLocation paremeter.

```
> root.очередь_за_95: Parameter entityLocation is not specified
> (null/empty) java.lang.RuntimeException: root.очередь_за_95: Parameter
> entityLocation is not specified (null/empty)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.error(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.error(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Utilities.error(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Conveyor.H(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.libraries.processmodeling.Conveyor.onStartup(Unknown
> Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.a(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.a(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Agent.start(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.Engine.start(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.i(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.ExperimentSimulation.run(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.c(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.gui.ExperimentHost.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.a.onCommand(Unknown Source)
>     at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$null$9(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:112)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.internal.webserver.g.acceptToAnimationSvgSession(Unknown
> Source)
>     at com.anylogic.executor.basic.rest.BasicAnimationSessionController.lambda$startController$10(BasicAnimationSessionController.java:112)
>     at spark.ResponseTransformerRouteImpl$1.handle(ResponseTransformerRouteImpl.java:47)
>     at spark.http.matching.Routes.execute(Routes.java:61)
>     at spark.http.matching.MatcherFilter.doFilter(MatcherFilter.java:130)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.internal.z.g$1.k(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.QoSFilter.doFilter(QoSFilter.java:201)
>     at com.anylogic.engine.internal.z.g$1.doHandle(Unknown Source)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1568)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:530)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:347)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:256)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:279)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:102)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:124)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:247)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.produce(EatWhatYouKill.java:140)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:131)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:382)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:708)
>     at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:626)
>     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Tried removing Source, delay and SelectOutput5 - no difference.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of inside `очередь_за_95`?

Comment: @YasharAhmadov you mean this? https://imgur.com/a/M0LtwkC

i'm noob in anylogic ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Yes, it seems you are using conveyors, but without telling the agent locations. There in `agent location` part, select where you want the agent to be.

Comment: @YasharAhmadov what if the list is empty and i cannot choose anything?

Comment: You need to create ones, then...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few blocks in AnyLogic that cannot work without corresponding animation objects. Conveyors are one of them.

See example below you need to draw a path and then select the path in the conveyor setup for the conveyor to work

[image]

There are currently two types of conveyor blocks in AyLogic, the one in the Process Modeling Library and the one in the Material Handling LIbrary. You used the former, I would recommend the latter. Check some of the documentation here.

https://anylogic.help/markup/conveyor.html